# Animation on beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

How to set this kind of animation on beamer?

> show_me_first  show_me_second.

I'm trying to show this sentence as described. The `show_me_first` is showed first, and on click oon the Down button, it will shows the `show_me_second`. How to deal with this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Two possibilities, depending on the intended overlay format:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{first}\only<2>{second}

\onslide<3>{third} \onslide<4>{fourth}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `\pause`:

```
\begin{frame}
first\pause second
\end{frame}
```

You could also take a look at the beamer manual for `\alt` and `\temporal`.

Here's an example of several overaly specifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> \only<1>{first}\only<2->{second}
\item<3-4> \onslide<3->{third}\onslide<4>{ fourth}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But that doesn't work on itemizes. when I try `\item \only<1>{first}\only<2>{second}` I get errors.

Comment: @Djouma of course it works. Let me update my answer with a simple example.

Comment: You're right, but I'm just trying to display the second part on click and to do not hide the first.

Comment: @Djouma Use `<1->` instead of `<1>`.

Comment: @Djouma please see my updated answer showing several options for overlay specifications.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
\begin{frame}
  \only<1-2>{show_me_first}
  \only<2>{show_me_second}
\end{frame}
```

Best regards,
Charlie