# inserting animation frames on separate slides

Tags: beamer, animations

Is there a quick way to put animation frames (from pdf) on separate slides (in beamer)? I know I could just include page by page on separate slides, but seeing that I have over 100 pictures in a single pdf, I'm looking for a better solution - something, perhaps, that would work like a loop. I can separate pictures to single files, but the problem remains: I'd have to create >100 frames and manually change name of picture file every single time. I'd appreciate any tips that could speed up a process. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There is the [animate-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate?lang=en) for real animations, but it only works with acrobat reader. In a presentation it would be better use `tikz` to draw the image and `\pause`, `\only`, `\onslide` etc. for transitions (see [Animation on beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177057/123129).

Comment: With the `pdfpages` package you can include a range of full pages at once. To include them as images inside the frame, I suggest `\multiinclude`

Comment: multiinclude did the trick! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by comments