# Simple beamer animation: output visualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I'd like to learn how to perform some simple animations in Latex. I tried to run this MWE (from
[Animate Line / Path using Tikz and 'animate' package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75580/animate-line-path-using-tikz-and-animate-package)), but it does not work: I can run the code, but this does not produce any animation. Why?

```
\listfiles 

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{animate} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{3} 
\multiframe{10}{rPos=0.1+0.1}{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[] 
\node (s){A}; \node (r) at (1,0) {}; 
\node (t) at (1,-2) {}; 
\node (v) at (0,-2) {B}; 
\path (s) -- (r) -- (t)--(v) node[pos=\rPos,coordinate] (p) {}; 
\draw[->, draw=black!70, line width=2.5] (s) -- +(r)--+(t)--+(p); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\end{animateinline} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

---

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(senza-nome-3.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2018/02/20 v3.50 A class for typesetting presentations

(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.
sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasedecode
.sty)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoption
s.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\xxcolor.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty")

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaserequir
es.sty
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecompat
ibility.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasefont.s
ty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sansmathaccent\sansmathaccent.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty")))
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetransl
ator.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator.sty"))
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemisc.s
ty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetwoscr
eens.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoverla
y.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetitle.
sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasesectio
n.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframe.
sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseverbat
im.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframes
ize.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframec
omponents.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecolor.
sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenotes.
sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetoc.st
y)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetempla
tes.sty
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseauxtem
plates.sty
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseboxes.
sty)))
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaselocals
tructure.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\enumerate.sty"))
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenaviga
tion.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetheore
ms.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty"))
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasethemes
.sty))
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerthemedefau
lt.sty
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerfontthemed
efault.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamercolortheme
default.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerinnertheme
default.sty)
(C:\Users\Caroline\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beameroutertheme
default.sty)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.code.tex"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\animate\animate.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\ifdraft.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\zref-abspage.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\zref-base.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\media9\pdfbase.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3pdfmode.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ocgx2\ocgbase.sty")) (senza-nome-3.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
(senza-nome-3.out) (senza-nome-3.out)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-basic-dictionary-
English.dict")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-bibliography-dict
ionary-English.dict")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-environment-dicti
onary-English.dict")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-months-dictionary
-English.dict")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-numbers-dictionar
y-English.dict")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-theorem-dictionar
y-English.dict") (senza-nome-3.nav){C:/Users/Caroline/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/
pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <a0,fr0> <a0,fr1> <a0,fr2> <a0,fr3> <a0,fr4>
<a0,fr5> <a0,fr6> <a0,fr7> <a0,fr8> <a0,fr9> [1] (senza-nome-3.aux)

 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2018/02/20 v3.50 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 animate.sty    2019/04/09 PDF & SVG animations from files and inline graphics
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifdraft.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Detect class options draft and final (HO)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
zref-abspage.sty    2016/05/21 v2.26 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2016/05/21 v2.26 Module base for zref (HO)
 pdfbase.sty    2019/05/24 v0.32 driver independent access to low-level PDF fea
tures
   expl3.sty    2019-05-28 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-05-28 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2019-05-28 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
 ocgbase.sty    2019/05/24 v0.15 support package for ocgx2.sty
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
senza-nome-3.out
senza-nome-3.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
 ***********

 )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb>
Output written on senza-nome-3.pdf (1 page, 28598 bytes).
SyncTeX written on senza-nome-3.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on senza-nome-3.log.
```

Comment: You might want to specify which PDF viewer you are using? Not all PDF viewers (other than Adobe) supports animations (AFAIK)

Comment: I'm using Adobe

Comment: The animation runs for me in Adobe Pro

Comment: In fact I have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: Should not make any difference. Exactly which versions of beamer etc are you using? Try adding `\listfiles` this prints a list of package versions into the log, then update your question with this information.

Comment: I use MiKTeX Package Manager 2.9.6515 (updated in december 2017). How should I add \listfiles in the MWE and how should I update my question?

Comment: Make sure JavaScript has not been disabled in the Reader preferences.

Comment: @AlexG yes, from edit-->preferences it seems to be enabled. is it possible that JavaScript is not installed on my pc?

Comment: No, it is built into the reader. Do the animations contained in the`animate` documentation run, if you open it in A-Reader?

Comment: Do you mean the documentation "animate.pdf" on CTAN (sorry for the dumb questions, but i'm newbie)? If so, yes, they run

Comment: @KJO This is visible from the link I provided above, in my question.

Comment: @KJO it still doesn't work, I do not understand why.

Comment: @KJO this happens with every animation... I tried to lunch the code in the accepted answer by Gonzalo Medina https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177057/animation-on-beamer, but it produces 4 different pages, and there is no animation. It though suffices to run the code once with pdfLatex, right? I mean, there are no further steps to perform to visualize the animation, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it does...

Comment: In fact I noticed right now that I can see the animations only if I open the .pdf separately... So maybe I misunderstood how beamer animations work, since I was expecting to see the animation immediately after running the code.

Comment: So,you too have to open the pdf externally?

Comment: ok! that seems to solve my problem thus. thank you for your time and patience, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this issue. I misunderstood how beamer animations work, since I was expecting to see the animations immediately after running the code. Instead, I noticed that I can see the animations only if I open the .pdf externally. As suggested by @KJO, only some editors use secondary viewers with animation. Thus, it is necessary to switch from internal to external, and this is a fundamental (and critical!) step that, as a newbie, I didn't consider.

Comment: It is worth noting that the external viewer must be a JavaScript-enabled one, e. g. Acrobat or Foxit.